# How to order tables in SQL by date

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, date

I have in database tables: table1, table2, table3... All of them have column date_table1, date_table2,..That columns have dates which are the same for all rows in that table, for example, table1 have column date_table1 that have date 2013-01-01, and it have that same date in all rows, table2 will have for example date 2013-01-02 and it will have only that date, that value. So, I need to sort my tables by date, i need to get list of the table names sorted from the earliest date until the latest. Can anyone help?

Comment: Without sample data and desired output, I am pretty sure I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: are you asking to sort the data within the tables? by Date? yet all rows Dates are identical?

Comment: If i understand you correctly you want the table names sorted by the data inside them. Well. If that is true, this is a little weird request. You might be better off putting some more thought into designing your database so that you don't have to go through your tables in order to know where the data is.

Comment: you need to normalise your data.

Comment: If you don't know what normalise means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: I think I misunderstood when I answered previously. Your database layout is confusing, I think your problem might be better solved by correcting it. Otherwise, more details on the tables would be useful in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select tablename, thedate
from ((select 'table1' as tablename, max(date) as thedate from table1) union all
      (select 'table2' as tablename, max(date) as thedate from table2) union all
      (select 'table3' as tablename, max(date) as thedate from table3)
     ) t
order by thedate, tablename;
```

To add more tables, just add additional rows with the `union all`.  If you have a lot of tables, but the names of the tables in a column in Excel and use Excel functions to generate the SQL code.

EDIT:

I actually like Matt's approach more (that he mentions in a comment):

```
select tablename, thedate
from ((select 'table1' as tablename, date as thedate from table1 limit 1) union all
      (select 'table2' as tablename, date as thedate from table2 limit 1) union all
      (select 'table3' as tablename, date as thedate from table3 limit 1)
     ) t
order by thedate, tablename;
```

Without indexes on `table<n>(date)`, this will run much faster.

Comment: is working but i get my tables sorted but i have repeating for example: table1,table1,table2,table2,table2...,they are sorted by the date but do you know maybe how to get them without repeating: table1,table2...

Comment: @zeka . . . This query should be returning one row for each table.  If you have duplicates, then you might be repeating a table multiple times in the `from` clause.  Or, you might have left out the `max()`.

Comment: All the dates in a table are the same, so you need to add `LIMIT 1` to each inner `SELECT 'table1' ...` statement or add `DISTINCT` around tablename so it is `SELECT DISTINCT(tablename), thedate FROM...`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ouu yea, my bad, tnx Gordon

Comment: @Matt . . . I actually like your approach better and just edited the question to use it.  The `limit 1` isn't needed for the first to work, but it would make the query run faster.